# Notification action not working in Android

Tags: android

I have this code

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context,WidgetAlarmManagerActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, launchIntent, 0);

            Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Nicilis")
                    .setTicker(messageBody)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, "Cancel Upload", pendingIntent)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

The action is in the notification but when I press it, nothing happen

Thanks a lot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context,WidgetAlarmManagerActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, launchIntent, 0);
```

`getBroadcast()` returns a `PendingIntent` that will invoke `sendBroadcast()` on the wrapped `Intent`. `getActivity()` returns a `PendingIntent` that will invoke `startActivity()` on the wrapped `Intent`. `WidgetAlarmManagerActivity` seems like the name for an activity, suggesting that you should replace `getBroadcast()` with `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, launchIntent, 0);
```

you should use be using

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, launchIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```